# AngularFirestore Missing or Insufficient permission (Firebase custom token auth)

Tags: javascript, angular, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security, angularfire

I have been trying to read data from firestore but unable to do so...

```
async authUser() {
    let token = this._tokman.getUserToken();
    await this._afa.signInWithCustomToken(token);
  }
```

getting the token from server and passing it to firebase to authenticate user.
Then calling firestore to get data..

```
async data() {
    await this._afa.onAuthStateChanged(user => {
      if (user) {
        this._afs.collection('gps-data').doc(user.uid)
          .valueChanges()
          .subscribe(res => {
            console.log(res);
          }, err => {
            console.log(err);
          })
      }
    })
  }
```

but getting this error from firestore.

```
FirebaseError: Missing or insufficient permissions.
at new e (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:51950:23)
at http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:62177:28
at http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:62178:18
at e.onMessage (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:62200:10)
at http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:62117:26
at http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:62148:37
at http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:66953:31
at ZoneDelegate.invoke (http://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:460:30)
at Zone.run (http://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:219:47)
at http://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:953:40
```

And firestore security rules are

```
 service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /gps-data/{userid} {
        allow read: if request.auth.token.sub == userid;
    }
   
  }
}
```

Also adding jwt token to http headers.
Please guide me where I am doing wrong.

**UPDATE**
Solved by : changing firebase version
*From*

```
"firebase": "^7.0 || ^8.0"
```

*To*

```
"firebase": "^8.0.2"
```

Without changing the security rule

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the `token.sub` in this line:

```
request.auth.token.sub == userid;
```

The `sub` of a token is the project ID for which that token was minted. So you're comparing a project ID with a user ID, and of the two are never the same.

You want to compare two user IDs here, which is:

```
request.auth.uid == userid;
```

I highly recommend spending some time reading the documentation on security rules, specifically the section on [securing authentication](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-conditions#authentication) and in [allowing only the content-owner access](https://firebase.google.com/docs/rules/basics#content-owner_only_access).

Comment: You can get uid from two places one from auth and another from idToken if you are using custom token. uid:  [link](https://ibb.co/27M2H7C). Anyways thanks for the help.